# Facebook JS SDK - Login popup doesn't close

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The below binds the login event to a div. If I click it, I get the expected js sdk login popup. After submitting the popup with my credentials, however, the popup turns white and doesn't close. If I refresh the page, I'm logged in, but it doesn't auto refresh as you might expect. Anyone got any ideas?

---

Edit: The same code (with diff app id and domain credentials) works on a different server. This leads me to believe that my problem might be unrelated to the below code. Are there any app or server configs that could cause the login popup to fail to close / update?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js ie ie10plus" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div id="fbLogin">Test login link</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
        <script>               
              var fbmm = {};

              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : '339910146083688', // App ID
                  cookie: true, 
                  xfbml: true,
                  status: true,
                  oauth: true
                });

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#fbLogin").click(function(){
                        console.log('test');
                         FB.login(function(response) {
                           if (response.authResponse) {
                             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                               console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                             });
                           } else {
                             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                           }
                         });
                    });
                });

              };

          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
           }(document));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is fine, working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Philip. My dialog window is not closing on the port 8000 domain though, when I'm unauthenticated and log in. I'm not sure, but you might need to log out of facebook and click it to see the bug.

Comment: I logged out and the window is closing after login. i run it at port 80 with my app_id. In your app url settings, have you add the url with the port?

Comment: The field "App Domains" does not seem to allow for port specification.

Comment: Hi @Matrym i have that same problem - How did you solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some known problems when testing on ports other than 80 or 443. Try setting up your test machine on one of these (“normal”) HTTP(S) ports, and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem occurs since you do not provide a channel url, as mentioned in the [documentation (under the Channel Url section)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript):

> The channel file addresses some issues with cross domain communication
>   in certain browsers.
>   ...
>   The channelUrl parameter is optional, but
>   recommended.

Even though your problem is not listed in the three issues the channel file solves, I experienced the same problem as you once and solved it by adding the channel, though it was a while ago so I'm not 100% it's the same.
It is explained there how to create the channel file, and you need to change your javascript just a bit:

```
FB.init({
    appId: '339910146083688', // App ID
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true,
    status: true,
    oauth: true,
    channelUrl: YOUR_CHANNEL_URL
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, that was one of my guesses as well. I tried putting a channel file in and it didn't work.

Comment: Just make sure that the channel is served from the exact same domain, including ports, also it turns out that there are are 2 bug reports which might be relevant. [Fb Login button does not trigger back, and keep hanging after successful login](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/421137377931628) also usesa different port so maybe what @CBroe wrote is the case, the 2nd: [Fb.login in explorer 7 show blank popup and doesn't close itself](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255683901207692) is for IE7 so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar call to `FB.login()` to close the dialog box by changing

```
onclick="loginviafb()";
```

to

```
onclick="loginviafb(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try to customize the app log-in with the auth dialog customization options in the app settings. There you can configure the permissions you want and facebook will automatically redirect to the app-auth page if the user is not logged in / authorised your app. You have to first enable it from the app settings > Auth Dialog. See the Click here annotation in the image below. Hope this helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when the development website address was `http://localhost` I defined a host in the windows hosts file and it worked ok.